# One word per bar on bar plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this df

[image]

With this code:

```
df.T.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(16,8),colormap=ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("husl", 10)), width=1.3)
plt.xticks(range(5), ['Bitcoin','Binance Coin','Ethereum','Monero','Ripple'],rotation=0);
```

I got this plot

[image]

How do I get one bar for each name and with different colors?

Comment: Try `df[0].plot(kind='bar')`?

Comment: by doing that , every bar has the same color

Comment: `sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df[0])`

Comment: thats, it , thanks !